# raster::writeRaster: when saving separate layers of a raster stack/brick, is the order of layer consistent with its name?

Tags: r, raster

> b is a raster brick with 19 layers named from **bio1** to **bio19**.
> I have successfully run the code, but I am not sure if the saved raster is exactly what it was originally named, like is the saved raster **bio1** really the same as the layer **bio1** in b?

`writeRaster(b, filename=names(b), bylayer = T,format="GTiff")`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah is the same. See the docu for `bylayer` in `writeRaster`: 
if TRUE, write a separate file for each layer. You can provide a vector of filenames that matches the number of layers. Or you can provide a single filename that will get a unique suffix (see below)